# How to use OpenGL/3D acceleration in virt-manager with ubuntu?

Tags: graphics, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, opengl, virt-manager

Currently on Ubuntu 20.04 both as host and guest, I followed http://ryan.himmelwright.net/post/virtio-3d-vms/ and activated 3D acceleration on video, and OpenGL on dsplay, but on VM launch I get

SPICE GL support is local only for now and incompatible with -spice port/tls-port

How can I make it work?

**UPDATE:**

I disabled Listen Type to None

like this[image]

but I get a very glitchy image:

[image]

Comment: how can i connect to the gui of a kvm virtual machine when 
spice server listen type is None ? 
Under virt-manager the console is just a black window. 
I can start a  RDP/VNC Server inside the vm but I want to use the spice Protocol to connect from the host to the VM

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL + 3D Rendering work great with iommu if you have VT-d support on your motherboard + processor. First look up your hardware to see if it supports VT-d. If it does, do the following:

Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` as root (use `sudo`), adding the following to the line beginning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`:

For Intel, `intel_iommu=on iommu=pt`. for AMD, `amd_iommu=on`. Eg.:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

[image: adding iommu boot flags to /etc/default/grub file]

After saving and closing, type `grep CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub` in your terminal. If you did everything right, you will see the line you edited with the new code. Eg.:

```
$ grep CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_iommu=on iommu=pt"
```

Then, run `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes and reboot.

(`update-grub` is a shortcut on Debian-derived distros for the command `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`)

Some observations on this:

1. It should be noted that this is a "weak" passthrough (shared) mode, that does not take over the entire device. "True" passthrough completely removes the device from control of the host. That requires a `vfio-pci=vendId:devId` stub either in grub or `/etc/modprobe.d` (and a rebuild of initramfs). For more information on passthrough, this is a good place to start: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF
2. There's even more elaborate ways of sharing your graphics, each vendor has their own version. For example, Intel-GVT-g for intel iGDs:  https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Intel_GVT-g

Here's my `xml` for the devices in question:

Display Spice - note: with passthrough you cannot enable a remote server:

```
<graphics type="spice">
  <listen type="none"/>
  <image compression="off"/>
  <gl enable="yes"/>
</graphics>
```

[image: Display Spice Server PCI passthrough w/ openGL config]

Video Virtio (change from QXL):

```
<video>
  <model type="virtio" heads="1" primary="yes">
    <acceleration accel3d="yes"/>
  </model>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
</video>
```

[image: changing from QXL to virtio for 3d acceleration]

Unrelated, I'm using a zvol block device on Ubuntu's ZFS installer config.  It's an option available in the Ubuntu Desktop version only:

[image: ZFS zvol for NTFS block device]

zvols are really cool because you can switch between using them for `kvm-qemu` and `[systemd-container][5]` (linux only, obviously) - plus snapshot and send / receive them.

But since zvols mimic a regular disk, they demonstrate that you could use a dedicated disk for your VM if you have room to install one, as well.

Once you make the zvol, give it a gpt partition structure using `fdisk/sgdisk/{g}parted` etc. just like you would any other disk. Once I created the gpt partition, I used the Windows ISO to do the actual partitioning.

`btrfs` has something similar which should be better supported by `systemd-nspawn`, but I am not sure if you can operate them like a block device in `qemu`.

Last tip: I needed to copy some files from the host to the VM. You can't really mount a folder from Linux --> Windows, but I could mount the partition (#3) Windows created on the zvol in the host as a regular NTFS partition.

So while the VM was off, I mounted partition 3 on `/mnt`, copied the folder I needed, `umount /mnt` the partition and start the VM back up.

Sometimes it's a little tricky to figure out what to do in that situation, so I thought I'd throw that in.  People in guides I've read have also recommended setting up Samba sharing if you need something more frequent, or I also remote to Windows VMs using OpenSSH-Server and PSRemoting, as well, so there's lots of options (Windows even has SSHFS now, if you check out [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)).

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem while working on software based Hardware Acceleration as specified by: http://ryan.himmelwright.net/post/virtio-3d-vms/ .
I tinkered around a little bit and found simple a solution which worked for me. But I cannot guarantee that it will work for you too:

I assume you have changed the 'Model' from 'QXL' to 'Virtio' and enabled '3D Acceleration' in 'Video Device' section along with the settings you specified above. I also assume the renderer that you have selected in the 'OpenGL' dropdown is your Dedicated GPU.

Now, just close your virt-manager instance and restart it from terminal by appending `DRI_PRIME=1` before it i.e. run `DRI_PRIME=1 virt-manager` in terminal. Now start your VM. Initially, I saw some screen glitches, but after the login screen was opened, the things ran smoothly. I monitored my AMD DGPU usage through `radeontop` and it was running fine.

**Note:**

1. The same solution worked with VirtualBox when it was not using my DGPU even with 3D Acceleration enabled. I also noticed that the 3D Acceleration was more stable in VirtualBox compared to Virt-manager.
2. Even after successfully enabling 3D acceleration, you will not get full GPU performance and will probably run into driver issues at various places. You would probably want to use your GPU directly into VM through GPU pass-through to overcome these problems.

**Edit 1:**

After more fiddling with the VM hardware acceleration, I found that there is one more step that needs to be done to run the VM with the DGPU. We need to first increase the VRAM to atleast 512MB in the 'QXL Model' of the 'Video Device' section, click 'Apply', change the 'Model' from 'QXL' to 'Virtio' with '3D Acceleration' enabled, and then run the virt-manager with `DRI_PRIME=1`.

When I tried this, Manjaro was running fine, but the performance of Windows 10 VM was very choppy.

Comment: I have no glitches but I still get the video in just 1/4 of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Since the initial question

> SPICE GL support is local only for now and incompatible with -spice port/tls-port
>
> How can I make it work?

has already been answered by the author

> I disabled Listen Type to None

it's worth to notice that the remaining issue is most likely related to the graphics card and the drivers installed on the host. People are especially reporting problems with nvidia cards:

- https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/164436
- https://forum.artixlinux.org/index.php/topic,3725.0.html
- https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/qro1jm/3d_acceleration_with_qemukvm_and_virtmanager_not/