# Virt-manager OpenGL (virgil) acceleration gets only 1/4 of screen

Tags: virtualization, opengl, 3d

I'm trying to use virgil OpenGL acceleration on ubuntu 20.04.2 both host and guest, but I get only 1/4 of the screen no matter what I do:

[image: ation]

It's an intel i7 11th gen, Iris Xe GPU (Dell XPS 13)

**UPDATE**: as pointed out below, the problem is with scaling. How can I make this work with scaling on?

Comment: It's probably an issue of scaling. Your laptop screen uses a (maybe 2x?) HiDPI scaling setting, yet `virt-manager` does not seem to support this. Maybe you should try GNOME Boxes?

Comment: @galexite indeed I use scaling, but I'd like to stick with virt-manager

Comment: I guess the acceleration needs to paint directly which makes the later scaling incompatible. What does happen if you bump up the resolution in the guest - does it get bigger then?

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt nothing happens, stays the same

Answer (score 0):

Check this link;
[How to use OpenGL/3D acceleration in virt-manager with ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1348975/how-to-use-opengl-3d-acceleration-in-virt-manager-with-ubuntu)

It looks like they were having a similar issue and they found a work around.
Good luck!

Comment: this is also me